# Showing that the sets $P_n = \{x \in X\mid |f(x)| \leq n, \forall f \in A\}$ are closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space and $A$ a set of continuous functions $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the sets $S_x = \{f(x)\mid f \in A\}$ are bounded for each $x \in X$. Define $P_n = \{x\in X\mid |f(x)| \leq n, \forall f \in A\}$. I'm currently a bit stuck in the following argument why each $P_n$ is closed. Below is my current attempt:

By the assumption on $A$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $P_n \neq \varnothing, \forall n \geq n_0$. So let $n \geq n_0$ and $(x_l)_{l \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a converging sequence in $P_n$. Let $f \in A$ be arbitrary, but fixed. Then $\lim_{l\to\infty}f(x_l) = f(\lim_{l\to\infty}x_l) = f(x)$, or equivalently $\lim_{l\to\infty}|f(x_l) - f(x)| = 0$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $l_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\epsilon > |f(x_l) - f(x)| \geq ||f(x_l)| - |f(x)||, \forall l \geq l_0$.

(**Thoughts:**) What I would like to do in my last step is to utilize the fact that $|f(x)| \leq k$, but I don't know how. Hints and tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Or use the fact that any intersection of closed sets is closed: $P_n = \bigcap_{f\in A} \{x:|f(x)|\leq n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have the right idea, you just need to use the fact that $x_l \in P_n$ for every $l$ means $|f(x_l)| \leq n$ for all $l$ and all $f \in A$:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $P_n=\emptyset$ then we are done.

Suppose $P_n \neq \emptyset$.

Let $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence of points from $P_n$. By assumption, $|f(x_k)| \leq n$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$ and all $f \in A$. Since every $f \in A$ is continuous, we have $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_k)=f(x)$ for every $f \in A$. We combine to conclude that

$$|f(x)|=\lim_{k \to \infty} |f(x_k)| \leq n.$$

Thus $x \in P_n$.